# Calculating intervals between events

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

What is a good way to record time between user events on iPhone?  ie. time between pressing Button_A and Button_B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more accurate way than using `[NSDate date]` is to use the `timestamp` property of the `UIEvent`.  To get the `UIEvent`, make sure you use the two-argument form for the target-action method.

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender event:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSTimeInterval timestamp = event.timestamp;
    NSTimeInterval secondsSinceLastEvent = timestamp - lastTimestamp;
}
```

Comment: There you go.  `lastTimestamp` is an ivar holding the timestamp from the first event.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can adapt such code to your situation :

```
NSDate *start = [NSDate date];
//do some stuff
NSLog(@"%f seconds elapsed", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:start]);
```

For example, write `start = [NSDate date];` in your Button_A action, and `NSLog(@"%f seconds elapsed", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:start]);` in your Button_B action.

Answer (score 0):

Create an NSDate object when the buttonA was pressed and then whenever the buttonB is pressed get the time elapsed since now by like this:

```
[[NSDate now] timeIntervalSince:buttonADate];
```